# Passing Key/Value from a dictionary into a .config file c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, config

I made the function below where I load the keys from two .config files into two dictionaries and later compare those dictionaries and change the value if they are different or I add a new key/value pair if it doesn't exist.
But now I need to add them again to the .config file replacing the older values and/or adding the new pair to it.
Can I do it such as if it was a .txt or is there a better way?
This is the function:

```
 public void UpdateClient(string FilePathOld, string FilePathNew)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> Old = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> New = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configOld.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathOld;
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            ExeConfigurationFileMap configNew = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configNew.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathNew;
            Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configNew, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
            Old = settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings2 = config2.AppSettings.Settings;
            New = settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);

            //Old = (config.GetSection("<appSettings>") as System.Collections.Hashtable)

            if (Old.Count == New.Count) // Require equal count.
            {

                foreach (var NewKey in New)
                {
                    string value;
                    if (Old.TryGetValue(NewKey.Key, out value))
                    {
                        if (value != NewKey.Value)
                        {
                            Old[NewKey.Key] = NewKey.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Old.Add(NewKey.Key, NewKey.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

> Is there a better way to do this rather than using dictionaries? A
>   more "direct" way ?

Comment: On face value your code looks like it should work - what seems wrong with it?

Comment: I've never worked with .config files, Im not getting how I will pass this key/value into the .config file.
For example I search in the .config file for a key thats in the dictionary and a then change its key.
How can I do this?
Do I have to treat the .config like it's a .txt? Sorry Im a bit confused because I've never worked with this two things before

Comment: Well they are like dictionaries, so, while I dont get why you'd have multiple settings files, surely the new settings is all you need, you just check they are different and copy the new over the old?

Comment: What I need to do is this: I have two config files, the old version and the new version. but on that same file (the old one) I cant change  certain key/value pairs because it was configured by the user during installation and cant be changed, however for all the other keys I need them to be updated with the new ones that can be found on the newest .config file.
Does this answer ur question?
And yes :) I check the differences and copy one over the other and add a new key/value it if doesnt exist's

Comment: OK that makes some sense. your if probably needs a few more criteria then such as if (!fixeditems.contains(newkey )) however, this should work perfectly well.  Remember to do a .Save() after!

Comment: I will have to add them to the file such af it was just another .txt file?
When adding the key/value pair will they be in a format like this:
**<add key="SqlTrans"            value="1" />**

Comment: Ive never looked - as Ive only ever used Properties.Settings.Default which is the default settings loaded (and you can update them) .. nope mine look like this <setting name="HideSuccess" serializeAs="String"><value>False</value>

Comment: I have an error on the this line:  `Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`
it gives me the following error.
 **An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: You do know that user configs cal detect new versions of exe and call upgrade to carry user settings over where possible right?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you want to say.
Can you be more explicit pls?

Comment: @BugFinder The code is retrieving 0 keys, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void UpdateService(string FilePathOld, string FilePathNew, string LatestVersion)
        {
                Dictionary<string, string> Old = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Dictionary<string, string> New = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                if (ExisteFicheiro(FilePathNew) == true && ExisteFicheiro(FilePathOld) == true)
                {
                    ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                    configOld.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathOld;
                    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                    ExeConfigurationFileMap configNew = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                    configNew.ExeConfigFilename = FilePathNew;
                    Configuration config2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configNew, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
                    Old = settings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings[key].Value);
                    KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings2 = config2.AppSettings.Settings;
                    New = settings2.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => settings2[key].Value);

                    foreach (var NewKey in New)
                    {
                        string value;
                        if (Old.TryGetValue(NewKey.Key, out value))
                        {
                            if (value != NewKey.Value)
                            {
                                //if (ExistsKey(NewKey.Key, false) == true)
                                Old[NewKey.Key] = NewKey.Value;

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Old.Add(NewKey.Key, NewKey.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var NewKey in Old)
                    {
                        string key = NewKey.Key;
                        string value = NewKey.Value;
                        if (config.AppSettings.Settings[key] != null)
                        {
                            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
                            if (key == "Version")
                                config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = LatestVersion;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);

                        }
                        if (config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"] == null)
                        {
                            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Version", LatestVersion);
                        }

                    }
                    config.Save();
                }
                else
                {
                    Erro NovoErro = new Erro();
                    Global.Erro = "O ficheiro \"OrcaService.exe.config\" ou o ficheiro \"Orca.exe.config\" não existem nos caminhos especificados!";
                }

        }
```

Done some work afterwords and this code works like a charm